# Finding input substring in string extracted from File

Tags: c, string, strstr

Basically, I would like to know why this code doesn´t work. It appears that the value of `strstr()` is always `NULL`, as all this code ever does is `"word not found"`.

I have already tried `if (strstr(retezec,substring)!=NULL)`, but it doesn't work either.

```
int main()
{

    FILE *files;
    files = fopen("Knihovna.txt","rb+");

    int i = 0;
    while(fgetc(files)!=EOF){
        i++;
    }
    //printf("%d",i);

    rewind(files);
    char *retezec;
    retezec = (char *)malloc(i);
    fread(retezec, i, 1, files);

    puts("zadejte hledane slovo");

    char *substring;
    substring = (char *)malloc(50);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(substring,49, stdin);

    char *found;
    found = strstr(retezec,substring);

    if(found){
        printf("word found!");
    }
    else{
        puts("word not found");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat - fstat to find out the length of the file

Comment: @EdHeal It's about learning C, not really about achieving something...

Comment: It seems you're using C++ compiler, as declaring variables between instructions is forbidden in C. Also, replace `char *substring=malloc(50);` by `char substring[50];`, it saves the trouble of `NULL` checking and forgetting to call `free()` (which you forgot...)

Comment: code blocks is what i use

Comment: @Matthieu Mixing declarations and statements in C is allowed since C99.

Comment: @Badministrator I guess it's high time I update my compiler then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely the result of [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) reading the trailing newline.

```
fgets(substring,49, stdin);
```

This would read the trailing newline if `substring` has space. So if you input `"name"`. You actually have `"name\n"`.

Remove the trailing newline with:

```
char *p = strchr(substring, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0; // remove the newline, if present
```

You have another problem. `fread()`doesn't NUL terminate. It simply reads the requested bytes. So you would need to check if `fread()` read `i` bytes or less and use that number (return value of `fread()`) to find the actual bytes read. Because it may be less than requested. And then, allocate one extra byte and NUL terminate it if you want to use it as a C-string.

Comment: it does seem to read as it should. Checked that with printing out the entire file (if that is what you mean. I am really NEW to programming and C in particular.

Comment: @VojtaMartinec It usually does. In case of failure, it may have read less `i` bytes. It's always best to check the return value of library functions/system calls than assuming success. You must NULL terminate it though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally solved.